# air sdk 16 buid app with ane,required to have universal iOS libraries. Please contact the ANE developer

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, chartboost, ane

I got a error when build air ios game with air sdk 16. when add a chartboost ane plugin(https://github.com/lilili87222/chartboost-ane-flash-air-android-ios)

Error: META-INF/ANE/iPhone-ARM/libAirChartboost.a, META-INF/ANE/iPhone-ARM libAirChartboost.a are required to have universal iOS libraries. Please contact the ANE developer(s) to get the same.

apple have announce app must support armv 64 01/02/2015.any idea?any body other have upgrade air sdk to 16?

Comment: it means the ane itself must be universal binary. You can't use it as it in a AIR 16 project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the source it's fairly simple to update as long as the extension is well coded in ObjC.

- open the Xcode project
- check that it's using the standard architectures and has arm64 a supported platform
- build the project

Then if you use the latest air beta to compile the ANE you'll get a 64 bit supported extension.

Comment: I am having the same problem. https://forums.adobe.com/message/7176133#7176133 .The static lib is reported to be fat by lipo -info with armv7 armv7s and arm64 so the ANE get compiled but when using the ane on a test app on Flash Pro CC fails